# Can I use Orleans for in process actors / grains?

Tags: c#, .net-core, orleans

I am playing with Orleans but instead of relying on network and hence the configuration of endpoints I would rather like to be able to have grains in process in the code below:

```
public interface IGreeter : IActorGrain
{
}

public class Greeter : DispatchActorGrain, IGreeter
{
    void On(Greet msg) => WriteLine($"Hello, {msg.Who}");
}

[SerializableAttribute]
public class Greet
{
    public string Who { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        WriteLine("Running example. Booting cluster might take some time ...\n");

        var host = new SiloHostBuilder()
            .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClusterId = "localhost-demo";
                options.ServiceId = "localhost-demo-service";
            })
            .Configure<SchedulingOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowCallChainReentrancy = false;
            })
            .Configure<SiloMessagingOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ResponseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                options.ResponseTimeoutWithDebugger = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .UseDevelopmentClustering(options => options.PrimarySiloEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 30000))
            .ConfigureEndpoints(IPAddress.Loopback, 11111, 30000)
            .ConfigureApplicationParts(x => x
                .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .WithCodeGeneration())
            .UseOrleankka()
            .Build();

        await host.StartAsync();

        var client = new ClientBuilder()
            .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options => {
                options.ClusterId = "localhost-demo";
                options.ServiceId = "localhost-demo-service";
            })
            .UseStaticClustering(options => options.Gateways.Add(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 30000).ToGatewayUri()))
            .ConfigureApplicationParts(x => x
                .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .WithCodeGeneration())
            .UseOrleankka()
            .Build();

        await client.Connect();

        var greeter = client.ActorSystem().ActorOf<IGreeter>("id");
        await greeter.Tell(new Greet {Who = "world"});

        Write("\n\nPress any key to terminate ...");
        ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible out of the box in Orleans 2.3. They have a "hosted client" (sometimes referred to as a "direct client") in the service container by default. Unfortunately, there are no docs for it yet. Additionally, it looks like you're using Orleankka. I haven't looked at that library in detail, so I'm not sure how configuration of the silo with a hosted client differs (if at all) from vanilla Orleans.

Comment: @seniorquico thanks, oooh nice, hope it can improve the startup time, otherwise it's really wayyyyy to slow :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally possible to use Orleans as a single process without clustering (which I did during testing and pre-production stages), but you will lose availability.

Silos are supposed to be running as long-running processes in a cluster so ~30 seconds startup time of a single node should never be an issue for cloud environments. If you need a single-host actor system, akka.net might be a better solution